# Passing authorization token in Jmeter - selinium web driver

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I am having bearer token in CSV file and implemented CSV config
How can i pass that in webdriver sampler Jmeter
based on the token only i can able to view my application

Answer (score 0):

Given you use [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the language in the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) you can use [Chrome Dev Tools protocol](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/) for this, example code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v106.network.Network
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v106.network.model.Headers

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()


def chromeDevTools = WDS.browser.getDevTools()

chromeDevTools.createSession()

chromeDevTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()))

WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')

Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
String auth = 'Bearer ' + vars.get('variable-from-your-csv-file')
headers.put("Authorization", auth);
chromeDevTools.send(Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders(new Headers(headers)))

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Comment: I am getting this error.Script7.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v106.network.Network. is there any jar file need to add

Comment: i am using java version "1.8.0_231" need to upgrade

Comment: You need to download [selenium-devtools-v106-4.6.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-devtools-v106/4.6.0/selenium-devtools-v106-4.6.0.jar) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (or any other folder which is under [`user.classpath` JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization). JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up